# How to import attributes in description WP ALL IMPORT

Tags: xml, wordpress, woocommerce, import, wpallimport

i have a xml with attributes syntax like below

```
<attribute_group name="Specs">
        <attribute name="color">White</attribute>
        <attribute name="series">Basic</attribute>
        <attribute name="power">40 W</attribute>
        <attribute name="voltage">220 V</attribute>
        <attribute name="SPL">90 dB</attribute>
        <attribute name="material">Wood</attribute>
        <attribute name="package">1 Pair</attribute>
</attribute_group>
```

I want to import them in product description (not like attributes) and create something like this

Specs

color : White

series : Basic

power : 40 W

voltage : 220 V

SPL : 90 dB

material : Wood

package : 1 Pair

The problem however is that the attributes are not arranged properly, not in the same order and not all products have same attributes
(some have more, some have less) the only standard is <attribute_group name="Specs">

How can I import it using wp all import module for woocommerce?

--------------------------------------------------

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask on [WP ALL IMPORT plugin support pages](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-all-import/).

Answer (score 0):

I did this, try pasting this code into the description field (replace parameters - "params/param")

```
[FOREACH({params/param})][ENDFOREACH]
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>{@name}</td>
<td>{.}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```